# Clicking on thunderbird notifications does not focus client

Tags: awesome, thunderbird

I get thunderbird popup notifications in Awesome Window Manager that when clicked, are supposed to focus the message to which the notification corresponds.

However, this does not work in awesome when thunderbird is on another tag.

So, to clarify, clicking on the T-bird notification should switch to the tag where T-bird is running, and focus T-bird.

Anyone know if this can be made to work?

```
% awesome --version && thunderbird --version && cat /etc/issue 2>&1
awesome v3.5.1 (Ruby Tuesday)
 • Build: Sep 12 2013 20:14:11 for x86_64 by gcc version 4.8.1 (nobody@)
 • Compiled against Lua 5.2.2 (running with Lua 5.2)
 • D-Bus support: ✔

Thunderbird 24.0
Arch Linux \r (\l)
```

Comment: Could you also include the awm and thunderbird versions as well as your OS? Never know what might be relevant.

Comment: @terdon edited per your request